# How to Mock a newly created object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Very simplified version of code:

```
interface IFactory
{
    ITreasure Get(SomeData data);
}

class Factory : IFactory
{
    ITreasure Get(SomeData data)
    {
         // Create instance of ITreasure in very long chain of methods basing on "data"
         // Can produce one of: BlueTreasure, RedTreasure or GreenTreasure
         return treasure;
    }
}
```

And here it is, the class with smell that **I can not** modify at all.

```
class CantModify
{
    public CantModify {}

    public TestMe(SomeData data)
    {
        ITreasure treasure = new Factory().Get(data);

        if(treasure is BlueTreasure) ...
        else if(treasure is RedTreasure) ...
        else if(treasure is GreenTreasure) ...
    }
}
```

I would like to test all code paths of **TestMe()** but I don't want to prepare **data** to obtain specific type of ITreasure. 
Is there any way to make **new Factory()** return Mocked instance of **Factory** that will return different type of ITreasure in each test?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't without changing CantModify

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dependency on IFactory in the Cantmodify class. And then you can Mock Get Method to return whatever you want.
The class should look :

```
public class CantModify
{
    private readonly IFactory _factory;

    public CantModify(IFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

     public TestMe(SomeData data)
    {
        ITreasure treasure = _factory.Get(data);

        if (treasure is BlueTreasure) ...


    else if (treasure is RedTreasure) ...

    else if (treasure is GreenTreasure) ...

}
```

Comment: Thank You, I know that this is the best solution but I wanted to make everything to avoid modifying CantModify. It looks like I have to :(

Answer (score 1):

You can mock all future instances of `Factory` and by that you will be able to modify the behavior of `Get` method to fit in your test, for example I used Typemock isolator to create a test that check if the `treasure` is green:

```
 public string TestMe(SomeData data)
 {
     ITreasure treasure = new Factory().Get(data);

     if (treasure is BlueTreasure) { return "blue"; }
     else if (treasure is RedTreasure) { return "red"; }
     else if (treasure is GreenTreasure) { return "green"; }
     return null;
 }


 [TestMethod,Isolated]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var fakeFactory = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<Factory>();
    var green = new GreenTreasure();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeFactory.Get(null)).WillReturn(green);

    var res = new CantModify().TestMe(new SomeData());

    Assert.AreEqual("green", res);
}
```